# In Python using Tkinter problem with fileopendialog return argument

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

I'm trying to write a code in Python importing Tkinter library and adding two Buttons:
1st Button with `def open_com` Opens a file with fileopeningdialog.
2nd Button with `def read_com` Does some action with the file.

I am trying to make a variable `filename` where to hold the pathway to the file after pressing 1st Button, so later the 2nd Button can use the file.
For now it is writing the file path in an Label from which the 2nd Button is taking the file path.
But definitely I know that there is a possibility to define in the functions and return the file path in a variable, so the 2nd Button can read it.

```
filename = None

# Open the file
def open_com():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=getcwd(), title = "Select file", filetypes = [("Name","*.xlsx")])
    target_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
    flabel['text'] = target_path
    file_check = flabel['text']
    if 'xls' in file_check:
        done_label['text'] = "Read file"
    else:
        pass
    return filename

#Read/Use file
def read_com():
    global filename
    file_label = flabel['text']
    try:
        # filename = r"{}".format(file_label)
        wbI = load_workbook(file_label)
    except Exception:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information","File is invalid. Call Computer guy")
        return None
    except ValueError:
        tk.messagebox.showerror("Information","No such file. Call Computer guy")
        return None
```

I tried to write `filename = open_com()` before or after the functions, then it just opens the dialog box to select the file, but still the 2nd Button doesn't read the path.
I've looked for Callbacks, but still I don't understand how to use them in my case.

**The goal**
With 1st Button to *open File dialog box* and I can *Choose the file* and *Store the file path in a variable*. Then with the 2nd Button to *Read the file path* from the variable and do some action with the file.

Comment: Why don't you use the *global `filename`* instead?

Comment: Also you do not state what the issue you come across.

Comment: That's wierd. Now I tried with `global filename` and it return properly and the `def read_com` function could read it. Now I am totally confused. But thanks